# Solving pseudoternary encoding using array function and for loop | c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write down the steps how pseudoternary encoding works. It accepts numbers from the array **inputs** (1 or 0). Then it checks each element in the array. If the number is 1 the step will be "**no line**". The problem is the zeros. The first zero of the array has to print the message "**pulse goes up**" then for each zero it finds, it has to print down and up(the zeros can or not be in next to each other). I'm trying to make the else statement of my function work, and also the for loop in the main function has to end depending on the array length. A few examples below to get the point:

> 10010

outputs: no line,up,down,no line, up

> 0001

outputs: up,down,up,no line

> 11000

outputs: no line, no line,up down, up

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

void  Pseudo(int a[])
{               
    for(int b=0;b<8;b++)
        if(a[b]==1)
            cout<<"No line value is 1\n";
        else
        {
            //when it finds the first zero in the array the line firstly goes up
            //then when it finds the second zero it goes down
            //the zero can be the 
            cout<<"Goes up\n";  
        }
}

int main()
{
    //1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0
    int inputs[]={1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0}; //the number inputs
    //the correct steps to this array would be:
    /* -no line
       -pulse goes up
       -no line 
       -pulse goes down
       -no line
       -no line
       -pulse goes up
       -pulse goes down
    */
     cout<<"Pseudoternary encoding scheme\nImplementation of "; 
     for(int b=0;b<8;b++)
     {
         cout<<inputs[b];
     }
     cout<<endl<<endl;
     cout<<"Steps:\n";
     Pseudo(inputs);
}
```

Comment: Your code. Format it.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a `bool` variable where `false` means "up" and `true` means "down". Toggle this on each zero after you print out "up" or "down". Initialize to `false`.

something like

```
bool down = false;

for (...)
{
    if (a[b] == 1)
    {
        ...
    }
    else /* if (a[b] == 0) */
    {
        std::cout << (down ? "down" : "up") << '\n';
        down = !down;  // Toggle boolean value
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that is not gonna work, because I have to check each zero in the array and print the messages depending on the previous zeros. For example, if I have 000000 it will print up,down,up,down,up,down. Is that possible to do it with bool ? Actually the point is to find the first zero

Comment: I get that error : invalid operands of types 'const char [3]' and 'char' to binary 'operator<<

Comment: @Eternal Damn that [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)... ;) Add a couple of parentheses.

Comment: thanks a lot, you gave me a nice example to understand the problem :)

Comment: one more note: in the main function is that possible to stop the loop depending on the numbers in the array? For example if  I have 10 elements in the array I have to make the loop something like (for i=0;i<array.length;i++)

Comment: @Eternal Yes. Either use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129791/discussion-between-eternal-and-some-programmer-dude).